# Special configuration on xampp vs xampplite?

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried to run a php file on xampp which is installed in Ubuntu and WinXP.  Both result in error, but it is success when tried to run on xampplite in WinXP.  Any special configuration is need to be set on the full xampp version?  The php code is as the following:

```
<?php
    require_once('database.php');

    // Get category ID
    if(!isset($category_id)) {
        $category_id = $_GET['category_id'];
        if (!isset($category_id)) {
            $category_id = 1;
        }
    }

    // Get name for current category
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories
              WHERE categoryID = $category_id";
    $category = $db->query($query);
    $category = $category->fetch();
    $category_name = $category['categoryName'];

    // Get all categories
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM categories
              ORDER BY categoryID';
    $categories = $db->query($query);

    // Get products for selected category
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products
              WHERE categoryID = $category_id
              ORDER BY productID";
    $products = $db->query($query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<!-- the head section -->
<head>
    <title>My Guitar Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>

<!-- the body section -->
<body>
    <div id="page">

    <div id="header">
        <h1>Product Manager</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="main">

        <h1>Product List</h1>

        <div id="sidebar">
            <!-- display a list of categories -->
            <h2>Categories</h2>
            <ul class="nav">
            <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
                <li>
                <a href="?category_id=<?php echo $category['categoryID']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $category['categoryName']; ?>
                </a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <!-- display a table of products -->
            <h2><?php echo $category_name; ?></h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th class="right">Price</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $product['productCode']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['productName']; ?></td>
                    <td class="right"><?php echo $product['listPrice']; ?></td>
                    <td><form action="delete_product.php" method="post"
                              id="delete_product_form">
                        <input type="hidden" name="product_id"
                               value="<?php echo $product['productID']; ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="category_id"
                               value="<?php echo $product['categoryID']; ?>" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                    </form></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>
            <p><a href="add_product_form.php">Add Product</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>&copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?> My Guitar Shop, Inc.</p>
    </div>

    </div><!-- end page -->
</body>
</html>
```

The database has been created without any problem.  Thanks